# how to use predict in tensorflow js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I made a model in python and exported it to tensorflow js.
The model is classifying facial images to emotions, and there should be 7 categories.

I made a tensor from the image and used predict like so:

```
const prediction = model.predict(imageTensor);
```

my prediction is :

```
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 415,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "2",
  "scopeId": 197,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    7,
  ],
  "size": 7,
  "strides": Array [
    7,
  ],
}
```

how do I extract the result from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, I was using typescript and it was needed:
const prediction = (model.predict(
imageTensor
) as tf.Tensor).dataSync();

Answer (score 2):

Prediction is a tensor. If you want to access the data, you need to use `prediction.dataSync()`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried that, but I get this message: Property 'dataSync' does not exist on type 'Tensor<Rank> | Tensor<Rank>[]'.
  Property 'dataSync' does not exist on type 'Tensor<Rank>[]'.ts(2339) , I'm at a  loss....